# How to name a "domain name" without TLD?

Tags: url, url-rewriting, naming-conventions

Is there a specific name for this kind of *"domain name"* : `https://www.website` ?

It's neither a domain name, a hostname, or an URL (because there's no TLD), neither a Second-level domain (because there's `https://www.`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific name because there is nothing specific in your case.

`https://www.website` is an URL like any other ones, for hostname `www.website` which is on the TLD `website`, which is a gTLD, see https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/website.html

There is nothing special here. You are probably not aware that `website` is a new TLD.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, I wasn't aware that `website` is an TLD. As I was aiming to find an appropriated method name, I've chosen "preURL", since it's called right before setting the actual TLD (something classic, like `.com`, `.net`...)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "preURL". `https://www.website` is an URL, `www.website` is a  domain name, and `website` is a TLD, not more or less classic than any other one (you could see newer if you want, but technically that does not change anything at all)

Comment: You right, it isn't clear. One of my script's goal is to write valid URLs (from domain name) through several steps. At some point `website` (from `https://www.website`) is indeed my TLD, but the next step is to set the actual TLD (ie. `.com` from `https://www.website.com`). By adding the prefix "pre" and saying "preURL", I mean _"We're right before having an URL"_. Yup, definitely note clear. If you got any name suggestion I'm open, but in the end that's not crucial to my script (as I'll be the only one ever executing it :p)

Comment: "but the next step is to set the actual TLD (ie. .com from https://www.website.com" I still don't understand this and what do you mean by "preURL". Again `https://www.website` is a completely legit URL and the TLD is `website`. It is not `com`, it is `website` because there are now over 1500 TLDs, and `website` is a "newer" ones among many others.